# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist. User has no profile

Tags: python, django

I've read some other answers for this (almost) question but they didn't help. I have the following 2 files mixed for user and profile apps(?).
In other answers they said this happens if you don't use >objects.get_or_create or not making signals.py file you'll get this error but I've gone through both of those ways and no results. 
This is the traceback I get:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:3000/profile/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['blog',
 'users',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_cleanup',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/mahour_sanat/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/mahour_sanat/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/mahour_sanat/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/mahour_sanat/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/mahour_sanat/mahoursanat/users/views.py", line 38, in profile
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
  File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/mahour_sanat/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 225, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
  File "/home/wss/Desktop/projects/python/django/mahour_sanat/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 423, in __get__
    self.related.get_accessor_name()

Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/
Exception Value: User has no profile.
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

signal.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

models.py for profile model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

and this is the views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, ProfileUpdateForm, UserUpdateForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(
                request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:

        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Thanks for reading this :).

P.S. As I see in admin page, no profiles are made after registration (neither from site nor admin page).

Comment: Have you setup the signals by importing `signals` in the app's `__init__.py`?

Comment: Add related_name to the OneToOne field, `user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: @Sachin Should I just import it (it didn't work) or do something else?

Comment: @art06 Still the same.

Comment: Have  you applied migrations after the change?

Comment: @art06 Yes I have done it already.

Comment: @KuroshGhanizadeh can you confirm if the post save signal handler is getting executed ?

Comment: @Sachin I don't know how to confirm such thing. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Add a print statement, restart the server, create a new user and check the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good to see someone who's practicing Django with Corey's tutorial! It took me few days to catch what went wrong. Here's how I did it.

Your `views.py` looks like this:

```
@login_required()
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
```

Add one in `views.py` so that it looks like below

```
@login_required()
def profile(request):
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
```

If you happen to face same issue somehow, create a new account and go to profile page and see if it throws any error.

Comment: thanks solved this error but can you explain why we why we need to use .get_or_create function since we already creating and saving a profile by using signals?

Comment: @Sheraram_Prajapat Glad that you solved the issue. As for why, honestly I'm not sure. My takeaway was since object did not exist, I created new one. I assume it could be something to do with heroku itself...

Answer (score 0):

```
define all apps in the end of Installed apps.

Installed Applications:
[
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog', #use <your_app>.apps.<YourAppConfig (class name)> instead of app name
 'users',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_cleanup',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in views.py
after def profile you should call the get_or_create method for your Profile model so the view will look like this

```
@login_required()
def profile(request):
    Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
```